# How to annotate design patterns in a uml diagram

Tags: design-patterns, uml

Some of the design patterns are recognizable, if you know them, but other aren't. I want to share this information in the documentation. What is the best way to annotate the used design patterns on a uml class diagram? Are there any special annotations, or I can just use the comment annotation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no standard for it but some UML extension approaches exist to visualize design patterns with stereotypes or tagged values ([example](http://www.jot.fm/issues/issue_2002_07/article3/)). Even without having a formal profile for it, something like the following should be understandable:

```
+-------------------------+    +--------------------------+
| {observer role=subject} |--->| {observer role=observer} |
|        SomeClass        |    |      SomeOtherClass      |
+-------------------------+    +--------------------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no special annotations. Use proper names for classes and interfaces (like `CompositeSpecification`), and add comments to diagram.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot accept both answers. The name with the name is great, but I think the annotation from fab describes better the used patterns.